# Firestore get document by id on angular 2

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to get document by id in google firestore? is there some `get()` method? because I searched but didn't find a proper answer that suits to me :(

Update: `this.itemscollection.doc(id).get()` didn't worked for me

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this code

```js
this.itemscollection.doc(id).ref.get().then(function(doc) {
  if (doc.exists) {
    console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
  } else {
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

Comment: Why do you need the ref? I checked out a lot of examples and nobody uses it, so I get the same error always 'get is not a function'. Please explain me.

Comment: @sirandy are you using angularfire2 ?

Comment: @sirandy I believe angularfire2 creates a wrapper around firebase classes. Thats why you need .ref to get doc.exists which is a firebase function.

Comment: `.ref` is unneeded in my latest testing.

Comment: How do you set the collection? Where is this in any documentation? What is the .ref and why isn't it in any docs?

Answer (score 7):

the key to success working with angular 2( when using the package angularFire2 ) with firestore is to know that all the firestore methods in their official documention that manipulate single doc like 'get' 'set' 'update'  are child of the 'ref' method
Example insted

```
 firestore - this.itemscollection.doc(id).get() 
 angularfirestore2 - this.itemscollection.doc(id).ref.get()
-------------------------------------
 firestore - this.itemscollection.doc(id).set()
 angularfirestore2 - this.itemscollection.doc(id).ref.set()
```